# XSL: using checkbox to get results in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm generating the following form (checkboxes) in xsl (ver=1.0). I can generate the results with a dropdown menu where there is only one option contained in the results. Using the checkboxes, is there a way to display results when users check multiple checkboxes? For example, I need to count items and display the lines like this (below) when user checks department 1, department 2, and region 1:

```
Search results for: department 1 & 2, region 1
Total: 3 items
department 1: 1 item
department 2: 2 items
region 1: 2 items

lines:
This is line 1 of description of item 1.
This is line 2 of description of item 1.
This is line 3 of description of item 1.
This is line 1 of description of item 2.
This is line 2 of description of item 2.
This is line 3 of description of item 2.
This is line 1 of description of item 3.
This is line 2 of description of item 3.
This is line 3 of description of item 3.
```

Here is the form that my xsl generates:

```
<form action method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="dept" value="1">1
<input type="checkbox" name="dept" value="2">2
<input type="checkbox" name="region" value="region1">Region1
<input type="checkbox" name="region" value="region2">Region2
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="category1">Category1
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="category2">Category2
<input type="text">
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

The xml look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
    <item>
        <number>1</number>
        <dept>1</dept>
        <region>region1</region>
        <category>category1</category>
        <description>
            <pp>
                <line>
                    This is line 1 of description of item 1.
                </line>
                <line>
                    This is line 2 of description of item 1.
                </line>
                <line>
                    This is line 3 of description of item 1.
                </line>
            </pp>
        </description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <number>2</number>
        <dept>2</dept>
        <region>region1</region>
        <category>category2</category>
        <description>
            <pp>
                <line>
                    This is line 1 of description of item 2.
                </line>
                <line>
                    This is line 2 of description of item 2.
                </line>
                <line>
                    This is line 3 of description of item 2.
                </line>
            </pp>
        </description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <number>3</number>
        <dept>2</dept>
        <region>region2</region>
        <category>category2</category>
        <description>
            <pp>
                <line>
                    This is line 1 of description of item 3.
                </line>
                <line>
                    This is line 2 of description of item 3.
                </line>
                <line>
                    This is line 3 of description of item 3.
                </line>
            </pp>
        </description>
    </item>
</items>
```

Comment: That's what javascript is for.

Comment: @MatthewWhited can you please provide any example?

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, if you want to process user events (such as clicking a checkbox) within the browser (rather than posting the result back to the server) then you write some Javascript event handlers.

These days there is another way of doing it, which is to write all the event handling in XSLT, using Saxon-JS which is an XSLT 3.0 processor that executes in the browser, and which provides extensions to make it interactive. You would write code something like this (not tested):

```
<xsl:template match="input[@type='checkbox']" mode="ixsl:click">
  <xsl:result-document href="#search-results-area">
    <xsl:variable name="checkedBoxes" 
      select="../input[@type='checkbox'][ixsl:get('checked')]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="selectedItems" select="ixsl:source()//item[
        region = $checkedBoxes[@name='region']/@value
        and number = $checkedBoxes[@name='number']/@value
        and dept = $checkedBoxes[@name='dept']/@value]"/>
    <p>Search results for ...</p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$selectedItems"/>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:for-each select="description/p/line">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

That's just a sketch of the solution, but if you decide to go down this route we'll be happy to help you flesh it out.

More information on Saxon-JS is here:

http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml